# react-hook-form not working with Expo 49 : Unable to resolve "react-hook-form"

Tags: react-native, expo, node-modules, react-hook-form, metro-bundler

I'm working on expo project with typescript

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^49.0.21",
    "@hookform/error-message": "^2.0.1",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.3",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.2",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
```

SignUpScreen

```
import { useForm, Controller,SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form';
import { ErrorMessage } from "@hookform/error-message";
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';

 const { handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }, control,setValue,getValues,reset } = useForm<any>({
        resolver: yupResolver(registerSchema) ,
        mode: "onChange",
  });
```

**errors I got**

import { useForm, Controller,SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form';
this import give me :

> Unable to resolve "react-hook-form" from
> "src\screens\authScreens\signUpScreen\SignUpScreen.tsx"

and this : import { ErrorMessage } from "@hookform/error-message";
give this error

> Unable to resolve "react-hook-form" from
> "node_modules@hookform\error-message\dist\index.esm.js"

also import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';  give

> Unable to resolve "react-hook-form" from
> "node_modules@hookform\resolvers\yup\dist\yup.module.js"

**in browser** I got

> 1_Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
> (Internal Server Error)    2_Refused to execute script from
> 'http://localhost:8081/index.ts.bundle?platform=web&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true'
> because its **MIME type ('application/json')** is not executable, and
> strict MIME type checking is enabled.

and on android stuck in spalsh screen

**solutions I've tried**

1_ delete nodemodules and npm install

2_ edit metro and clear cache  :
metro.config.ts

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");

module.exports = (() => {
  const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
  const { transformer, resolver } = config;
  config.transformer = {
    ...transformer,
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
  };
  config.resolver = {
    ...resolver,
    assetExts: resolver.assetExts.filter((ext:any) => ext !== "svg"),
    sourceExts: [...resolver.sourceExts, "svg",'jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs','mjs','d.ts',
     'json']
  };
  
  return config;
})();
```

3_ uninstall and re-install the packages again

Comment: can you check if the `react-hook-form` is installed when you run `npm list react-hook-form`?

Comment: @Oluwafemi  ├─┬ @hookform/error-message@2.0.1
│ └── react-hook-form@7.49.2 deduped
├─┬ @hookform/resolvers@3.3.3
│ └── react-hook-form@7.49.2 deduped
└── react-hook-form@7.49.2

Comment: I tried with a [new project](https://github.com/osule/HookFormSample) and couldn't reproduce the error. Can you share a repository where this error can be reproduced?

Comment: according to https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/23322  it seems that expo 49 is incompatible with react-hook-form , because there's no way to make react hook form work  with expo 49 ,  I had to upgrade to Expo  50.0.0-preview.8  and it works with no issues . really thank you for your help @Oluwafemi Sule